# On MTLComputePipelineState what determines maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup?

Tags: ios, macos, shader, metal, metalkit

When working with Metal Shaders / Compute Kernels on iOS or MacOS...

`MTLComputePipelineState` has a limit of `maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup`.

This limit can be queried after the pipeline state is created. This limit is dependent on both GPU hardware characteristics, OS version, and your Metal kernel code.

- What aspects of Metal kernel code impact MTLComputePipelineState's maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup?
- What can be done to increase the value given a fixed hardware / OS combination?

For example:

- Register usage?
- Length of code?
- Forced inlining?

(The question isn't how to calculate the optimal sizes, it's about how to modify code to achieve the largest threadgroup.)

Link to Apple's docs for `MTLComputePipelineState`:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcomputepipelinestate/1414927-maxtotalthreadsperthreadgroup

Link to Apple's docs for "Calculating Threadgroup and Grid Sizes":
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/calculating_threadgroup_and_grid_sizes?language=objc